# Check if page is loaded through Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, session, cookies, facebook-page

I have a bit of a challenge. I have created a small gallery app that runs in a facebook fan page. All is well and working, but I would like to run a check if the user loads the page from pagebook or not and redirect to the fan page if needed.

I can get the signed request from Facebook when the page loads and store that in a session, but I don't see how I can contain that session to only the current browser tab? Would a cookie be better?

The problem is not the first pageload from Facebook to my pageapp but all the subsequent ones as the signed_request is no longer being passed by Facebook.

In simple terms: I need to store the signed_request only for the current browser tab. Is that possible?

Thanks :-)

Comment: What’s the concern here – that a user that already opened the app inside the page might “break out” of it, by opening internal links in a new browser tab? Is that app used on just one page, or multiple? If the former, then I would probably just check if it was loaded inside of an iframe at all via JS, and if not redirect.

Comment: currently it's only used on one page, but could potentially be multiple. The "break out" is a border case, but if I could prevent it, then I'd like to.

Comment: Well if that’s not the main case – then what is? And if the app is used on multiple pages – then which one would you want to redirect to, if the app was initially called outside of any page?